# angular cli change default environment when running ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run ng serve it uses default environment as dev. Is there a way to update angular cli to use a different environment file?

**Update**

Sorry, Should have been more clear in my question. I know we can use --env switch to specify the environment file to use, but was wondering if there is a way to change the default environment file selection when no env is specified. Currently we have environment.local.ts file, I am trying to update angular cli configuration to use environment.local.ts when no environment is specified.

Comment: FWIW this is a feature request tracked here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1923

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue as you, and couldn't find a way to override the default environment variable used when no env arg is passed, but found a workaround that worked for me:

Simply change the file path that is standing for the `dev` environment in the
angular cli configuration file (angular-cli.json):

```
// ...
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.local.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
},
// ...
```

`dev` is the default environment variable used by Angular CLI if no args are passed, so the `local` file would be the used one.

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 6+ follow these instructions:

First you will define your environments in your angular.json, create those files, and then you will run via "ng serve --configuration dev"

This document covers the details of the above:

https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/environment-variables-angular/

Additionally you will need to define the same in the "serve" section of the JSON...i.e:

> ```
> "serve": {
>  [...]
>  "configurations": {
>    "production": {
>      "browserTarget": "myApp:build:production"
>    },
>    "debug": {
>      "browserTarget": "myApp:build:debug"
>    }
>  }
> ```

Comment: But don't like that --configuration dev flag to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the --environment option through the CLI:

`ng serve --environment prod` will use the `environment.prod.ts` file.

You can also configure your environments in `.angular-cli.json` file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue with the `@angular/cli` version, please remove/uninstall the current version of your `@angular/cli` by using the following command.

```
"npm remove @angular/cli" --save-dev
```

and then install the latest version like :

```
"npm install @angular/cli@1.3.0" --save-dev
```

I hope default environment issue will be solve.

Answer (score 0):

```js
"options": {
            "browserTarget": "rcyc-admin:build:uat"
          },
```

For angular version 7 , you just need to set default serve->options->browserTarget to env file name
like in my case its "browserTarget": "cat-admin:build:**uat**".
Or you can add new inside serve->configurations with your environment files like this

```js
"production": {
  "browserTarget": "rcyc-admin:build:production"
},
"uat": {              
   "browserTarget": "rcyc-admin:build:uat"
},
```

and call using

```
 ng serve -c uat
```

in angular-cli.json

**Not recommended This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally**